# Centering a floated div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to center a floated div. The `.imgContainer` element must have a
`float:left` attribute because otherwise the code breaks. I have tried `display:inline-block` but that causes my jquery code to stop working correctly.

What i have tried to do is wrap it in a `wrap` div and then try to center that div which that isn't working either.

I have created a codepen to demonstrate my issue. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjGwNw

Html:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="galleryWrap">
    <a class="fancybox imgContainer" data-fancybox-group="gallery" data-filter="projects"><img src="http://www.devsourcecodex.com/images/advertisingexamples/200x200.png" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="fancybox imgContainer" data-fancybox-group="gallery" data-filter="websites"><img src="http://www.devsourcecodex.com/images/advertisingexamples/200x200.png" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="fancybox imgContainer" data-fancybox-group="gallery" data-filter="projects"><img src="http://www.devsourcecodex.com/images/advertisingexamples/200x200.png" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="fancybox imgContainer" data-fancybox-group="gallery" data-filter="websites"><img src="http://www.devsourcecodex.com/images/advertisingexamples/200x200.png" alt="" /></a>


    <a class="fancybox imgContainer" data-fancybox-group="gallery" data-filter="projects"><img src="http://www.devsourcecodex.com/images/advertisingexamples/200x200.png" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="fancybox imgContainer" data-fancybox-group="gallery" data-filter="websites"><img src="http://www.devsourcecodex.com/images/advertisingexamples/200x200.png" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="fancybox imgContainer" data-fancybox-group="gallery" data-filter="websites"><img src="http://www.devsourcecodex.com/images/advertisingexamples/200x200.png" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="fancybox imgContainer" data-fancybox-group="gallery" data-filter="websites"><img src="http://www.devsourcecodex.com/images/advertisingexamples/200x200.png" alt="" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
  .wrap {
   float: left;
   position: relative;
   left: 50%;
 }

 .imgContainer {
   width: 400px;
   height: 400px;
   border: solid 1px #999;
   margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   float: left;
   position: relative;
   left: -50%;
 }

 img {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this css and let me know if that is what you imagined.

```
 .wrap {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
 }

 .imgContainer {
   width: 400px;
   height: 400px;
   border: solid 1px #999;
   margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
 }

 img {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks but my .imgContainer much contain a float:left because otherwise if i remove that it messes with my Jquery code and stops it from working correctly.

Comment: i see you have changed the image container to width and heigth 400px. centering that div would make it look like this: http://codepen.io/jascha/pen/oXJGwP 
not sure if that is what you wanted though